# Add component (JButton) to JTable with jtableBinding

Tags: java, swing, binding, jtable

I use `jtableBinding` every where in my program, and use binding list to `JTable` for show data. But now I want add component (`JButton`) to a column. I try this code but not work.

```
    columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${button}"));
    columnBinding.setColumnName(bundle.getString("tblSpkhtgiri8"));
    columnBinding.setColumnClass(JButton.class);
    columnBinding.setEditable(false);
```

But not show any thing in this column. 
I can't change method for show data in table for example use `Vector` and can't remove bundling.

Comment: 1) *"jTableBinding"*  What on Earth is that?  Link to it..  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: I try write question with SSCCE.But I'm a novice in English Language.

Comment: If you are using the [JGoodies](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jgoodies/info) `JTableBinding`, update the tags accordingly and use a fully qualified name.

Comment: Ok @AndrewThompson I careful after then. :D